# Why is isset function inconsistent to other functions like empty?

Tags: php

Here's a list of test (which all got errors including expressions):

```
php > isset(1); // integer

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in php shell code on line 1
php >     isset('string'); // string

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in php shell code on line 1
php >     isset(null); // null

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in php shell code on line 1
php >     isset(['q']); // array

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in php shell code on line 1
php >     isset(1==1); // expression

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in php shell code on line 1
php > isset("null !== expression")
php > ;

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in php shell code on line 1
```

but when tested with empty:

```
   empty(1); // integer
   empty('string'); // string
   empty(null); // null
   empty(['q']); // array
   empty(1==1); // expression
   empty("null !== expression");
```

no errors.. I'm aware of the warning in the manual 
`Warning
isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.`

But would like to know why anyway.. why is it like that?

Comment: How does it make sense to ask whether something that isn't a variable has had a value set?

Comment: isset() is to check if a variable has been declared.. empty() checks if a variable is empty.

Comment: Joseph Sible Yes, but shouldn't that return false for consistency with the other native functions? I find it quite weird

Comment: It's not a function, but a language construct that just happens to look like a function.

Comment: I will have to request on the php.net site

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] 
It will be fixed as a feature on the upcoming php7 patch